# Redshift data API: programatically set MaxResults for getStatementResult

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm using the newly released Redshift Data API.

I'd like to programmatically paginate the query results which are returned from the `getStatementResult` action.

According to the API reference, `getStatementResult` returns a `NextToken` property, which implies it supports pagination.

However, I couldn't find a `Limit` or `MaxResults` argument:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift-data/latest/APIReference/API_GetStatementResult.html

To make things more confusing, the CLI operation does support pagination using the `--starting-token` and `--max-items` arguments:
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/redshift-data/get-statement-result.html

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to paginate `getStatementResult` results programmatically?
2. If not, then what's the meaning of the `NextToken` which is returned from `getStatementResult`? What is the default page size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case this is relevant for anyone, as of October 2020 this is not possible via the API.

See answer from AWS employee here:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=329141&tstart=0